# How would run a python command using windows?

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to run the following command from a windows computer that I am familiar with using linux but I am not sure how to on windows

```
python3 create_db.py --output data/imdb_db.mat --db imdb --img_size 64
```

I have anaconda installed if that helps but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it using the anaconda prompt or command prompt. I can run programs from the Spyder editor but using the ipython console inside spyder does not work either.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the path of the `python3.exe` and use that:

```
C:/path/to/python3.exe create_db.py --output data/imdb_db.mat --db imdb --img_size 64
```